# Wanted process monitor WITH logging to file (Win)

Tags: windows, monitoring, logging

I was very surprised when to not find process monitor, which could be able to doing their work, and save some dumps with the specified periodicity. Does anyone know such like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's another [**Systinternals**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx) tool called [**PSList**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896682.aspx) that will give you a process list from the command line.  You can create a scheduled task to run it.  Let's you do list processes remotely as well.  Create a batch file that redirects output to a file, schedule it and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Create a shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
ps aux >> /path/to/log.file
```

Add it to your crontab and have it run however often you'd like. This will take the output of the 'ps aux' command and APPEND it to the file you specify. If you want it to overwrite, use a single '>'.

Comment: You'll need something like Cygwin for this to work in Windows

Comment: Yes, thank you. I just noticed the 'Windows' flag... I'm new here. If you are trying to do this on a Windows machine, something like Cygwin is definitely required.

Comment: no worries!  The windows tag I believe was edited in after your answer.  Welcome to SF! :)

Comment: it was added after your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) with the backing file option to capture process info to a file.  See Procmon help for more details.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative strategy, you could turn on [Process Tracking](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775520(WS.10).aspx) in your auditing options. This causes event log entries to be generated when processes start, end, etc (details about the log entries in the link above). Then, rather than seeing a "snapshot" of the machine at a given instant you'll see a log of all processes. Obviously, you'll have to parse the event log to get at the information you're looking for, but this method guarantees that a process won't be hidden by starting and stopping in between static "snapshot" intervals.